# Function defined with return type has no return statement?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello, World\n");
}
```

In the code above (originally shown as a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikiAZ.png)), the return type for the `main` function is `int` but we are not returning any value in that function. 
This function works even without the return statement.

How is that possible?

Comment: `main` is special.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Please don't post pictures of code, post the actual code. If the picture is removed, the question turns into nonsense, because nobody is going to know what you are talking about.

Comment: [don't put code in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @Pablo it's not about the image link going to die, it's about people not be able to copy the code and test themselves, and also not being able to search content in the code

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc For me it's about both. If the picture is gone and in the feature another use finds this question, then it will be waste of time, because the code is gone and the question won't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

As of [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf), it's well-defined.

§ 5.1.2.2.3 Program termination

> reaching the `}` that terminates the `main` function returns a value of 0.

Answer (score 1):

In C99 and [C11 §5.1.2.2.3 Program termination](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.3), the standard stipulates:

> #### 5.1.2.2.3 Program termination
>
> ¶1 If the return type of the `main` function is a type compatible with `int`, a return from the
>   initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value
>   returned by the `main` function as its argument;<sup>11)</sup> reaching the `}` that terminates the
>   `main` function returns a value of 0. If the return type is not compatible with `int`, the
>   termination status returned to the host environment is unspecified.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>11)</sup> In accordance with 6.2.4, the lifetimes of objects with automatic storage duration declared in `main`
>   will have ended in the former case, even where they would not have in the latter.

There was no similar provision in C90.  If you return from `main()` in a C90 program by falling off the end (rather than by executing a `return` with a value), the value returned to the environment is undefined.  The code still worked, but programs such as the shell could not reliably detect whether the program was successful or not.

> ISO/IEC 9899:1990
>
> #### 5.1.2.2.3 Program termination
>
> ¶1 A return from the initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function
>   with the value returned by the `main` function as its argument. If the `main` function executes a return that specifies no value, the termination status returned to the host environment is undefined.
>
> #### 6.6.6.4 The `return` statement
>
> ¶3 If a return statement without an expression is executed, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined. Reaching the `}` that terminates a function is equivalent to executing a `return` statement without an expression.

This paragraph is not present in [C11 §6.8.6.4 The `return` statement](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.6.4).

Thus, if your compiler supports C99 or C11, dropping off the end of `main()` is equivalent to `return 0;` but this was not the case before C99.  I believe this was done as much for conformity with C++98 (which has essentially the same rule) as for any other reason.

Speaking personally, I dislike the rule and my `main()` programs normally end `return 0;`.

Comment: I dislike it too. It gives wrong impressions, like what happened with the OP

Answer (score -1):

This is to keep the code compatible with earlier stages of C.

C compiler implicitly does it for you. :)
i.e

```
return 0;
```

Comment: How does it keep code compatible, and with which earlier stages of C?  The rule is incompatible with the earliest version of the C standard — C90.  It applies to the old (C99) and current (C11) versions of the standard, only.